# Firebase Authentication Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to android studio and Firebase. After watching some online tutorials I wrote the code for a login page. Can anyone please debug it for me?

Please note that my login button is an image view

The name of the app is Riddler

```
package in.mihiljose.riddler;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class LoginSignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;
    private ImageView mLoginBtn;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_sign_up);

        mEmailField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){

                    startActivity(new LoginSignUp().this,MainActivity.class);
                }

                }
            };
        }

        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startSignIn();

            }
        });

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }
}


    private void startSignIn(){

        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

            Toast.makeText(LoginSignUp.this,"Empty Fields !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginSignUp.this,"Sign in Problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        })


    }



}
```

Comment: Have you called "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" (sign in)  before doing login?

Answer (score 0):

Find this sample code for Login Activity: (Ensure you have done signIn using "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" before doing login)

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;
    private SignInButton btn_google_login;
    private LoginButton btn_facebook_login;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private AuthCredential mCredential;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };



        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    mCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authStateListener != null) {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private void SignOut() {
        //Firebase sign out
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            auth.signOut();
            Log.i("LoginActivity","Firebase logout successfully");
        }

        //Facebook SignOut
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("LoginActivity","onDestroy");
        SignOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: i just copy pasted your code and got the following errors:

Comment: class Login Activity is public,should be declared in a file name LoginActivity.java
cannot find symbol class CallbackManager

Comment: Just remove declared variables which are not used. CallbackManager & googleApiClient is not used. I have updated the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading data from Firebase's real time database, the default read database permission is set to false. You can modify it to true from the database's permission tab.